# jQuery: get parent tr for selected radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent, tablerow

I have the following HTML:

```
<table id="MwDataList" class="data" width="100%" cellspacing="10px">
    ....

    <td class="centerText" style="height: 56px;">
        <input id="selectRadioButton" type="radio" name="selectRadioGroup">
    </td>

    ....
</table>
```

In other words I have a table with few rows, in each row in the last cell I have a radio button.
How can I get *parent* row for selected radio button?

What I have tried:

```
function getSelectedRowGuid() {
    var row = $("#MwDataList > input:radio[@name=selectRadioGroup]:checked :parent tr");
    var guid = GetRowGuid(row);
    return guid;
}
```

But it seems like this selector is incorrect.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Try this.

You don't need to prefix attribute name by `@` in jQuery selector. Use `closest()` method to get the closest parent element matching the selector.

```
$("#MwDataList input[name=selectRadioGroup]:checked").closest('tr');
```

You can simplify your method like this

```
function getSelectedRowGuid() {
    return GetRowGuid(
      $("#MwDataList > input:radio[@name=selectRadioGroup]:checked :parent tr"));
}
```

`closest()` - Gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

As a side note, the ids of the elements should be unique on the page so try to avoid having same ids for radio buttons which I can see in your markup. If you are not going to use the ids then just remove it from the markup.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Here's the documentation for closest()
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 74):

### Answer

```
$("#MwDataList input[name=selectRadioGroup]:checked").closest('tr');
```

---

### How to find the closest row?

**Using `.closest()`:**

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

---

**Using `.parent()`:**

Check this [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method. This is alternative of a `.prev()` and `.next()`.

```
var $row = $(this).parent()             // Moves up from <button> to <td>
                  .parent();            // Moves up from <td> to <tr>
```

---

#### Get All Table Cell **`<td>`**

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),       // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td");             // Finds all children <td> elements

$.each($tds, function() {               // Visits every single <td> element
    console.log($(this).text());        // Prints out the text within the <td>
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CKEc6/1/)**

---

#### Get Only Specific **`<td>`**

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),        // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"); // Finds the 2nd <td> element

$.each($tds, function() {                // Visits every single <td> element
    console.log($(this).text());         // Prints out the text within the <td>
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T9uv7/)**

---

#### Useful methods

- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - get the first element that matches the selector
- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) - get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) - get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) - get the children of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) - get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) - get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) - get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements