# How to get the td based a certain condition

Tags: javascript

I have a  HTML tag like:

```
<tr class="evenRow" id="5"><td align="left" noWrap="nowrap">
    <input id="array_5" type="checkbox" value="on"/> </td>
    <td align="left" noWrap="nowrap">  SAMPLE </td>
    <td align="center" id="row_at_plant_0" noWrap="nowrap" class="data-current-value" row_index="2"> 1112</td>
    <td align="left" noWrap="nowrap">  1.0457 </td>
</tr>
```

I have this code to get the `<td>` tag that has `row_index` attribute when `array_*` is checked. But it's not working in IE.

```
$('table#headerSelectTable input[id^="array_"]:checked').each(function() {
    input = $(this).parent().parent().find('.data-current-value');

    if ($(this).parent().parent().get(0).tagName == 'TR') {
        rows.push(input);
    }
});
```

Comment: [here][1] is a similar question with a good sample


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314902/jquery-get-parent-tr-for-selected-radio-button

Comment: What is the value of `$(this).parent().parent().get(0).tagName` when it fails?

Comment: In what way is it failing? Is the selector not finding any checked boxes? Is `input` not getting set properly, is the `if` test failing?

Comment: input = $(this).parent().parent().find('.data-current-value'); is not working because when I try input.attr("row_index"), it returns "undefined"